# Webcam and IP camera video capture from Java

Tags: java, slf4j

I want to capture video from a web camera (an IP camera) using the Github API and Xuggler API.

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{
    System.out.println("I am inside main()");

    File file = new File("d:/output.ts");

            IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(file.getName());
            Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();

            writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, size.width, size.height);

            Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
            webcam.setViewSize(size);
            webcam.open(true);

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

                    System.out.println("Capture frame " + i);

                    BufferedImage image = ConverterFactory.convertToType(webcam.getImage(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                    IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);

                    IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(image, (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000);
                    frame.setKeyFrame(i == 0);
                    frame.setQuality(0);

                    writer.encodeVideo(0, frame);

                    // 10 FPS
                    Thread.sleep(100);
            }

            writer.close();

            System.out.println("Video recorded in file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

    }
}
```

The error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:   com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.IBuffer_make__SWIG_0(JLcom/xuggle/ferry/RefCounted;I)J
at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.IBuffer_make__SWIG_0(Native Method)
at com.xuggle.ferry.IBuffer.make(IBuffer.java:1088)
at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:21)
at com.xuggle.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.setMemoryModel(JNIMemoryManager.java:1190)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.<clinit>(MediaWriter.java:119)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory.makeWriter(ToolFactory.java:149)
at javaapplication10.VideoRecord.main(VideoRecord.java:34)
```

Comment: Did you check the link in the exception?

Comment: i've checked exception but not getting any improvement again same problem galovics